# disable click on range input for it's background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an application that uses spotify's apis, But I'm trying to set an input range thumb track to not 'expand' on click, although this error in the video occurs for some unknown reason.

I tried setting the range pointer-even attributes to things like, "auto" or "none" (with `!important` as well) but either or don't work. Any help?

Range's CSS:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.box-minmax {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 608px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.box-minmax span:first-child {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.range-slider {
    margin-top: -2vh;
}
.rs-range {
    margin-top: 29px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.rs-range:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.rs-range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    pointer-events: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
.rs-range::-moz-range-track {
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: visible;
}
.rs-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    background: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.rs-range::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.rs-range::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
}
.rs-label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -255px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    left: attr(value);
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
}
```

HTML:

```html
<form class="range-field w-64">
    <div class="range-slider">
        <input id="rs-range-line" class="rs-range" type="range" value="0" min="0">
        <span id="rs-bullet" class="rs-label">0</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbp2.jpg

Comment: the code you gave works well and the stripe doesn't expand. This code is not the problem. Give more code, or a link to the site.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I run a server on my internet connection, using localhost. I don't have a link. Also, If It's not a code problem, what could it be?

Comment: this is not a problem with the code you gave. maybe the problem is in other code in your project.

Comment: Nothing else seems to be using input. Could it be chrome?

Comment: I checked for chrome. Which browser do you have?

Comment: Well, I use Chrome.

Comment: see gif - https://ibb.co/Ct6DcwL

Comment: oh, well you're on a mac I think. Is it a system/browser version difference?

Comment: no, not a mac. this is linux, ubuntu. version browser 85.0.4183.121 (64 bit).

Comment: What is your Chrome's version?

Comment: Verion: 86.0.4240.183